# Solving ODE with 2 variable changes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I'm asked to solve the ODE $$xy'=y f(xy)$$ with the variable changes $x=e^t$, $y = u\frac{1}{x}$.

Applying $y = u\frac{1}{x}$ the equation turns into $$y'=\frac{u}{x^2}f(u)$$

and derivating $y = u\frac{1}{x}$ we get $$y'=\frac{u'}{x}-\frac{u}{x^2}$$

This leaves the equation in terms of $u$

$$u'=\frac{uf(u)+u}{x}$$

which is separable. Hence the family of solutions are functions satisfying the condition $$\int\frac{1}{uf(u)+u}du=\ln(x)$$

Is this correct? I'm not sure where I was supposed to use the change of variable $x=e^t$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With $x=e^t$ the equation has a some simpler form ($dx/dt=e^t$)

$$du=\frac{uf(u)+u}{x}dx\to du=(uf(u)+u)dt$$

$$\int\frac{1}{uf(u)+u}du=t$$

Maybe too the examples for a particular $f(u)$ you have to deal with are simplified by this variable change.